# Adding Selection field in React.js

Tags: reactjs

im new to react so exuse this question. How i add a selection field in this form.input. The options i want are student and teacher. Im following the Just Django school system project and some files are different form the video.

```
<Form.Input
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  type="select"
  placeholder="Select your position"
  options='student'
  options='teacher'
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with select like this way:

```
<select onChange={this.handleChange}>
<option> Select your position <option/>
<option>student<option/>
<option>teacher<option/>
<select/>
```